# tinyMCE error whe trying to get content

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am getting this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined`

```
if (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
                alert('editor exist')
                var myEditor = tinyMCE.get['rteCaseHeading'].getContent();
                $("#bookId").html(myEditor);
            }
```

In Html :

```
<textarea class="mceEditor" id="rteCaseHeading"  rows="10" cols="100" style="height: 300px"> </textarea>
```

I also have specified :   `editor_selector : "mceEditor",`during tinyMCE init.

I have referred various links/questions on this error and implemented.

This somehow still throws error though length of editors is greater than zero.

Someone , please suggest am struggling since more than 2-3 hrs with this issue. 
[UPDATE]

I referred this link 
and added the below code : http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/49/

```
 ed.on('change', function () {
                    ed.save();
                });
```

Still, no luck. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you calling the `.triggerSave();` method before using the `.getContent();` method?

Comment: Hello , I am not calling any other method. Could you please guide me here? I am using version 3.X . Thank You !

Comment: Hi David R, I read your comment and added  ed.save(); as well. Still no luck, Please suggest !

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your `<textarea>` inside `<form></form>` tags.

Checkout the below code,

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="action_page">
<textarea class="mceEditor" id="rteCaseHeading"  rows="10" cols="100" style="height: 300px">testtestet</textarea>
</form>

<button onclick="content()">Get content</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor"  
});

function content(){
    alert(tinyMCE.get('rteCaseHeading').getContent());
}
```

**Working Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/kqa13zz4/52/

**Note:** In fiddle, I have written the `function content()` function as `window.content = function()...` since fiddle accepts function declaration in that way only.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `get()` method correctly.  You have this:

var myEditor = tinyMCE.get['rteCaseHeading'].getContent();

...it should be this:

var myEditor = tinyMCE.get('rteCaseHeading').getContent();

The way you have things written you are trying to access an array on the tinyMCE object - but the `get` is a method not an array - it is a method on the tinyMCE object hence the need for parenthesis and not square brackets.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#get

(the method call is the same for TinyMCE 3 and 4)